# Error upgrading to High Sierra

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, terminal, mac, high-sierra

I just got a MacBook yesterday, but I haven't been able to upgrade it to High Sierra. I've tried upgrading from the App Store where I'm logged into my Apple ID, and from Recovery mode where I booted with `option + command + r` to get the latest High Sierra Recovery mode. The High Sierra installer error log below:

```
May  7 XX:XX:58 lilys-MacBook-Air.local InstallAssistant_plain[303]: Hardware: MacBookAir5,2 @ 1.80 GHz (x 4), 4096 MB RAM
May  7 XX:XX:58 lilys-MacBook-Air.local InstallAssistant_plain[303]: Running OS Build: Mac OS X 10.8.5 (12F2560)
May  7 XX:XX:58 lilys-MacBook-Air.local InstallAssistant_plain[303]: Env: PATH=/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
May  7 XX:XX:58 lilys-MacBook-Air.local InstallAssistant_plain[303]: Env: TMPDIR=/var/folders/xt/shdslw5j0n72jmzmsym0j4bh0000gn/T/
May  7 XX:XX:58 lilys-MacBook-Air.local InstallAssistant_plain[303]: Env: SHELL=/bin/bash
May  7 XX:XX:58 lilys-MacBook-Air.local InstallAssistant_plain[303]: Env: HOME=/Users/lily
May  7 XX:XX:58 lilys-MacBook-Air.local InstallAssistant_plain[303]: Env: USER=lily
May  7 XX:XX:58 lilys-MacBook-Air.local InstallAssistant_plain[303]: Env: LOGNAME=lily
May  7 XX:XX:58 lilys-MacBook-Air.local InstallAssistant_plain[303]: Env: SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/tmp/launch-xobZco/Listeners
May  7 XX:XX:58 lilys-MacBook-Air.local InstallAssistant_plain[303]: Env: Apple_Ubiquity_Message=/tmp/launch-br745g/Apple_Ubiquity_Message
May  7 XX:XX:58 lilys-MacBook-Air.local InstallAssistant_plain[303]: Env: Apple_PubSub_Socket_Render=/tmp/launch-xB7SqS/Render
May  7 XX:XX:58 lilys-MacBook-Air.local InstallAssistant_plain[303]: Env: COMMAND_MODE=unix2003
May  7 XX:XX:58 lilys-MacBook-Air.local InstallAssistant_plain[303]: Env: __CF_USER_TEXT_ENCODING=0x1F5:0:0
May  7 XX:XX:58 lilys-MacBook-Air.local InstallAssistant_plain[303]: objc[303]: Class OSISSystemInfo is implemented in both /Applications/Install macOS High Sierra.app/Contents/MacOS/InstallAssistant_plain and /Applications/Install macOS High Sierra.app/Contents/PlugIns/DiskManagement.IABundle/Contents/MacOS/DiskManagement. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
May  7 XX:XX:58 lilys-MacBook-Air.local InstallAssistant_plain[303]: FAILURE: Job com.apple.install.osinstallersetupd is not loaded in launchd.
May  7 XX:XX:58 lilys-MacBook-Air.local osinstallersetupplaind[307]: MiniSoftwareUpdate: Trust result constants not defined (expected on pre-10.9), disabling EV checks
May  7 XX:XX:58 lilys-MacBook-Air.local osinstallersetupplaind[307]: osinstallersetupd registered client
May  7 XX:XX:58 lilys-MacBook-Air.local osinstallersetupplaind[307]: OSISPredicateUpdateProduct: OS Installation Payload: Timed out loading catalog
May  7 XX:XX:58 lilys-MacBook-Air.local osinstallersetupplaind[307]: OSISPredicateUpdateProduct: OS Installation Payload: No products found.
May  7 XX:XX:58 lilys-MacBook-Air.local osinstallersetupplaind[307]: Predicate update product fetch failed with error: Error Domain=com.apple.OSInstallerSetup.error Code=300 "The recovery server could not be contacted." UserInfo=0x7f859184df30 {NSLocalizedDescription=The recovery server could not be contacted.}
May  7 XX:XX:55 lilys-MacBook-Air.local InstallAssistant_plain[303]: Connection to NetworkBrowserAgent became invalid
May  7 XX:XX:55 lilys-MacBook-Air.local InstallAssistant_plain[303]: Connection to NetworkBrowserAgent became invalid
May  7 XX:XX:55 lilys-MacBook-Air.local InstallAssistant_plain[303]: Connection to NetworkBrowserAgent became invalid
May  7 XX:XX:56 lilys-MacBook-Air.local osinstallersetupplaind[307]: OSISSoftwareUpdateController: Failed to load catalog https://swscan.apple.com/content/catalogs/others/index-10.13-10.12-10.11-10.10-10.9-mountainlion-lion-snowleopard-leopard.merged-1.sucatalog: Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1001 "The request timed out." UserInfo=0x7f8590c57f90 {NSUnderlyingError=0x7f859183f320 "The request timed out.", NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://swscan.apple.com/content/catalogs/others/index-10.13-10.12-10.11-10.10-10.9-mountainlion-lion-snowleopard-leopard.merged-1.sucatalog, NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://swscan.apple.com/content/catalogs/others/index-10.13-10.12-10.11-10.10-10.9-mountainlion-lion-snowleopard-leopard.merged-1.sucatalog, NSLocalizedDescription=The request timed out.}
May  7 XX:XX:03 lilys-MacBook-Air.local InstallAssistant_plain[303]: Connection to NetworkBrowserAgent became invalid
May  7 XX:XX:03 lilys-MacBook-Air.local InstallAssistant_plain[303]: Connection to NetworkBrowserAgent became invalid
May  7 XX:XX:03 lilys-MacBook-Air.local InstallAssistant_plain[303]: Connection to NetworkBrowserAgent became invalid
```

I'm not sure why the request "timed out", The MacBook is definitely connected to the internet. I could really use some help here.

MacBook specifications:

```
sh-3.2# system_profiler SPSoftwareDataType
Software:

    System Software Overview:

      System Version: OS X 10.8.5 (12F45)
      Kernel Version: Darwin 12.5.0
      Boot Volume: lily
      Boot Mode: Normal
      Computer Name: lily’s MacBook Air
      User Name: System Administrator (root)
      Secure Virtual Memory: Enabled
      Time since boot: 12:37
```

Comment: Check your Internet connection.

Comment: as stated above, im definitely connected to the internet. thanks

Comment: Not just connected, but not being blocked from certain sites.

Comment: yeah, i used safari and curl from Terminal to connect to google and duckduckgo. also able to login to my apple id and download the high sierra installer

Comment: also used curl to view `https://swscan.apple.com/`. it worked fine

Comment: Try re-downloading the installer and doing it via USB stick installer.  I greatly prefer this method.

Comment: @Allan thanks for the suggestion. would you be able to assist here? https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/324710/install-macos-high-sierra-app-does-not-appear-to-be-a-valid-os-installer-applica

Comment: I was just checking the size of my installer and it's 5.1GB.  I just created a USB installer for someone...I might be able to make it availabe to you for DL