# Install macOS Monterey.app does not appear to be a valid OS installer application. No /Volumes/Shared\ Support

Tags: install, monterey

Tried to make USB stick with Monterey installer and got `Install macOS Monterey.app does not appear to be a valid OS installer application`.

There is an answer on this portal [Install macOS Monterey.app does not appear to be a valid OS installer application](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/439402/install-macos-monterey-app-does-not-appear-to-be-a-valid-os-installer-applicatio), but where to get `/Volumes/Shared\ Support/`? I don't have such volume.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strange... Just removed `/Applications/Install macOS Monterey.app`, which I've placed here from `.dmg`, I've downloaded, and copied it again from `.dmg` to `/Applications` and it just works now. Very strange... Seems app has been broken during 1st copying process...