# Failed to verify InstallESDDmg.pkg: xar_verify failed

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, mac, high-sierra, recovery

Similar to [this issue](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/324700/error-upgrading-to-high-sierra), im still unable to upgrade to high sierra. **any advice** would be amazing right now since I'm getting a different error:

```
May  7 XX:XX:36 lilys-MacBook-Air.local InstallAssistant_plain[348]: Hardware: MacBookAir5,2 @ 1.80 GHz (x 4), 4096 MB RAM
May  7 XX:XX:36 lilys-MacBook-Air.local InstallAssistant_plain[348]: Running OS Build: Mac OS X 10.8.5 (12F2560)
May  7 XX:XX:36 lilys-MacBook-Air.local InstallAssistant_plain[348]: Env: PATH=/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
May  7 XX:XX:36 lilys-MacBook-Air.local InstallAssistant_plain[348]: Env: TMPDIR=/var/folders/xt/shdslw5j0n72jmzmsym0j4bh0000gn/T/
May  7 XX:XX:36 lilys-MacBook-Air.local InstallAssistant_plain[348]: Env: SHELL=/bin/bash
May  7 XX:XX:36 lilys-MacBook-Air.local InstallAssistant_plain[348]: Env: HOME=/Users/lily
May  7 XX:XX:36 lilys-MacBook-Air.local InstallAssistant_plain[348]: Env: USER=lily
May  7 XX:XX:36 lilys-MacBook-Air.local InstallAssistant_plain[348]: Env: LOGNAME=lily
May  7 XX:XX:36 lilys-MacBook-Air.local InstallAssistant_plain[348]: Env: SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/tmp/launch-DRI5PY/Listeners
May  7 XX:XX:36 lilys-MacBook-Air.local InstallAssistant_plain[348]: Env: Apple_Ubiquity_Message=/tmp/launch-9mMBh1/Apple_Ubiquity_Message
May  7 XX:XX:36 lilys-MacBook-Air.local InstallAssistant_plain[348]: Env: Apple_PubSub_Socket_Render=/tmp/launch-ZKXQJn/Render
May  7 XX:XX:36 lilys-MacBook-Air.local InstallAssistant_plain[348]: Env: COMMAND_MODE=unix2003
May  7 XX:XX:36 lilys-MacBook-Air.local InstallAssistant_plain[348]: Env: __CF_USER_TEXT_ENCODING=0x1F5:0:0
May  7 XX:XX:36 lilys-MacBook-Air.local InstallAssistant_plain[348]: objc[348]: Class OSISSystemInfo is implemented in both /Applications/Install macOS High Sierra.app/Contents/MacOS/InstallAssistant_plain and /Applications/Install macOS High Sierra.app/Contents/PlugIns/DiskManagement.IABundle/Contents/MacOS/DiskManagement. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
May  7 XX:XX:37 lilys-MacBook-Air.local InstallAssistant_plain[348]: FAILURE: Job com.apple.install.osinstallersetupd is not loaded in launchd.
May  7 XX:XX:37 lilys-MacBook-Air.local osinstallersetupplaind[353]: MiniSoftwareUpdate: Trust result constants not defined (expected on pre-10.9), disabling EV checks
May  7 XX:XX:37 lilys-MacBook-Air.local osinstallersetupplaind[353]: osinstallersetupd registered client
May  7 XX:XX:32 lilys-MacBook-Air.local osinstallersetupplaind[353]: Package Authoring: error running volume-check script: TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'my.evaluator.metainfo') at x-distribution:///installer-gui-script%5B1%5D/volume-check%5B1%5D/@script
May  7 XX:XX:33 lilys-MacBook-Air.local osinstallersetupplaind[353]: Package Authoring: error running volume-check script: TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'my.evaluator.metainfo') at x-distribution:///installer-gui-script%5B1%5D/volume-check%5B1%5D/@script
May  7 XX:XX:34 lilys-MacBook-Air.local osinstallersetupplaind[353]: No native mechanism to verify InstallInfo.plist
May  7 XX:XX:48 lilys-MacBook-Air.local osinstallersetupplaind[353]: Predicate update product fetch succeeded!
May  7 XX:XX:48 lilys-MacBook-Air.local osinstallersetupplaind[353]: Specifier (<PKPackageSpecifier>:
    {
        URL = "file://localhost/var/tmp/OSISPredicateUpdateProductTemp/Core.pkg";
        authLevel = 2;
        displayName = macOS;
        identifier = "com.apple.pkg.Core";
        options = 0;
        version = "10.13.4.0.0.1522206870";
    }) missing reference.
May  7 XX:XX:48 lilys-MacBook-Air.local osinstallersetupplaind[353]: Specifier (<PKPackageSpecifier>:
    {
        URL = "file://localhost/var/tmp/OSISPredicateUpdateProductTemp/EmbeddedOSFirmware.pkg";
        authLevel = 2;
        displayName = macOS;
        identifier = "com.apple.pkg.EmbeddedOSFirmware";
        options = 0;
        version = "10.13.4.0.0.1522206870";
    }) missing reference.
May  7 XX:XX:48 lilys-MacBook-Air.local osinstallersetupplaind[353]: Specifier (<PKPackageSpecifier>:
    {
        URL = "file://localhost/var/tmp/OSISPredicateUpdateProductTemp/SecureBoot.pkg";
        authLevel = 2;
        displayName = macOS;
        identifier = "com.apple.pkg.SecureBoot";
        options = 0;
        version = "10.13.4.0.0.1522206870";
    }) missing reference.
May  7 XX:XX:48 lilys-MacBook-Air.local osinstallersetupplaind[353]: Specifier (<PKPackageSpecifier>:
    {
        URL = "file://localhost/var/tmp/OSISPredicateUpdateProductTemp/Core.pkg";
        authLevel = 2;
        displayName = macOS;
        identifier = "com.apple.pkg.Core";
        options = 0;
        version = "10.13.4.0.0.1522206870";
    }) missing reference.
May  7 XX:XX:48 lilys-MacBook-Air.local osinstallersetupplaind[353]: Specifier (<PKPackageSpecifier>:
    {
        URL = "file://localhost/var/tmp/OSISPredicateUpdateProductTemp/EmbeddedOSFirmware.pkg";
        authLevel = 2;
        displayName = macOS;
        identifier = "com.apple.pkg.EmbeddedOSFirmware";
        options = 0;
        version = "10.13.4.0.0.1522206870";
    }) missing reference.
May  7 XX:XX:48 lilys-MacBook-Air.local osinstallersetupplaind[353]: Specifier (<PKPackageSpecifier>:
    {
        URL = "file://localhost/var/tmp/OSISPredicateUpdateProductTemp/SecureBoot.pkg";
        authLevel = 2;
        displayName = macOS;
        identifier = "com.apple.pkg.SecureBoot";
        options = 0;
        version = "10.13.4.0.0.1522206870";
    }) missing reference.
May  7 XX:XX:08 lilys-MacBook-Air.local osinstallersetupplaind[353]: Helper tool loaded
May  7 XX:XX:08 lilys-MacBook-Air.local osinstallersetupplaind[353]: Specifier (<PKPackageSpecifier>:
    {
        URL = "file://localhost/var/tmp/OSISPredicateUpdateProductTemp/Core.pkg";
        authLevel = 2;
        displayName = macOS;
        identifier = "com.apple.pkg.Core";
        options = 0;
        version = "10.13.4.0.0.1522206870";
    }) missing reference.
May  7 XX:XX:08 lilys-MacBook-Air.local osinstallersetupplaind[353]: Specifier (<PKPackageSpecifier>:
    {
        URL = "file://localhost/var/tmp/OSISPredicateUpdateProductTemp/EmbeddedOSFirmware.pkg";
        authLevel = 2;
        displayName = macOS;
        identifier = "com.apple.pkg.EmbeddedOSFirmware";
        options = 0;
        version = "10.13.4.0.0.1522206870";
    }) missing reference.
May  7 XX:XX:08 lilys-MacBook-Air.local osinstallersetupplaind[353]: Specifier (<PKPackageSpecifier>:
    {
        URL = "file://localhost/var/tmp/OSISPredicateUpdateProductTemp/SecureBoot.pkg";
        authLevel = 2;
        displayName = macOS;
        identifier = "com.apple.pkg.SecureBoot";
        options = 0;
        version = "10.13.4.0.0.1522206870";
    }) missing reference.
May  7 XX:XX:08 lilys-MacBook-Air.local osinstallersetupplaind[353]: OSISDownloadOperation: totalEstimate=794.000000, significantDownload=1
May  7 XX:XX:11 lilys-MacBook-Air.local osishelperd[368]: WARN: using mkdir instead of rootless_mkdir_nounlink because the platform does not support it.
May  7 XX:XX:11 lilys-MacBook-Air.local osishelperd[368]: Using fallback rootless_check_trusted because the platform does not support it.
May  7 XX:XX:11 lilys-MacBook-Air.local osishelperd[368]: WARN: using mkdir instead of rootless_mkdir_restricted because the platform does not support it.
May  7 XX:XX:11 lilys-MacBook-Air.local osishelperd[368]: WARN: using mkdir instead of rootless_mkdir_restricted because the platform does not support it.
May  7 XX:XX:12 lilys-MacBook-Air.local osinstallersetupplaind[353]: No native mechanism to verify BaseSystem.chunklist
May  7 XX:XX:50 lilys-MacBook-Air.local osinstallersetupplaind[353]: isConvertableToAPFS: was called on a APFS disk.
May  7 XX:XX:50 lilys-MacBook-Air.local osinstallersetupplaind[353]: Target is not convertible to APFS: This volume is not formatted as Mac OS Extended (Journaled).
May  7 XX:XX:06 lilys-MacBook-Air.local osinstallersetupplaind[353]: isConvertableToAPFS: was called on a APFS disk.
May  7 XX:XX:06 lilys-MacBook-Air.local osinstallersetupplaind[353]: Target is not convertible to APFS: This volume is not formatted as Mac OS Extended (Journaled).
May  7 XX:XX:19 lilys-MacBook-Air.local osinstallersetupplaind[353]: No native mechanism to verify BaseSystem.dmg
May  7 XX:XX:19 lilys-MacBook-Air.local osinstallersetupplaind[353]: No native mechanism to verify AppleDiagnostics.chunklist
May  7 XX:XX:24 lilys-MacBook-Air.local osinstallersetupplaind[353]: Failed to verify InstallESDDmg.pkg: xar_verify failed
May  7 XX:XX:24 lilys-MacBook-Air.local osinstallersetupplaind[353]: Retrying http://swcdn.apple.com/content/downloads/10/62/091-76233/v27a64q1zvxd2lbw4gbej9c2s5gxk6zb1l/InstallESDDmg.pkg after 1 failure(s)
May  7 XX:XX:51 lilys-MacBook-Air.local InstallAssistant_plain[348]: Connection to NetworkBrowserAgent became invalid
May  7 XX:XX:51 lilys-MacBook-Air.local InstallAssistant_plain[348]: Connection to NetworkBrowserAgent became invalid
May  7 XX:XX:51 lilys-MacBook-Air.local InstallAssistant_plain[348]: Connection to NetworkBrowserAgent became invalid
```

the logs state "This volume is not formatted as Mac OS Extended (Journaled).", if its referring to the built-in 250 GB APPLE SSD, then thats incorrect, the drive is definitely formatted as "Mac OS Extended (Journaled)", i verified using Disk Utility. there are no other drives (internal or external) connected to the device.

Comment: the installer was at about 45% completed, then the "failed to verify" and "retrying swcdn.apple.com" errors appeared. wtf

Comment: possibly, yeah, if the origin of the issue(s) are found to be the same. currently, the error messages are different enough to warrant a new post. thanks

Comment: Is FileVault on?

Comment: Have you considered first installing [El Capitan](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT206886), then upgrading to High Sierra? If this works, you could then try a clean install of High Sierra.